# Random elements (coordinates)

Tags: c#, random

I have to do something like this.

[image]

When I click on a node, it expands, and this is OK (I am using Powercharts to do it).
My big problem is creating random coordinates so that when I open the subnode, it doesn't overlap with another node/subnode.

In the Powercharts I have to pass the coordinates, so the big problem is in passing it.

I have to do the random coordinates in C#.

//-------------------------------------------------------

This is what i did so far:

This is what i do, is not overlaping, but i have a problem.
how can i start do the circles from a starting point?
for example, starts in the middle (300,300) and then do circles around it. Is possible?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);

            double angle;
            Circle item0 = new Circle();
            item0.x=200;
            item0.y=150;
            item0.r=50;
            listaCirculos.Add(item0);

            Random randomMember = new Random();
            g.DrawEllipse(pen1, 200, 150, 50, 50);

            while(listaCirculos.Count!=11)
            {
                int[] it = GenerateNewCircle(600);
                Circle item = new Circle();
                item.x = it[0];
                item.y = it[1];
                item.r = 50;

                if (circleIsAllowed(listaCirculos, item))
                {
                    listaCirculos.Add(item);
                    g.DrawEllipse(pen1, Convert.ToInt32(item.x), Convert.ToInt32(item.y), 50, 50);
                }
            }


        }

        bool circleIsAllowed(List<Circle> circles, Circle newCircle)
        {
               foreach(Circle it in circles)
               {
                  //double sumR = it.x  + newCircle.r; 
                  //double dx = it.x - newCircle.x; 
                  //double dy = it.y - newCircle.y; 
                  //double squaredDist = dx * dx + dy * dy; 
                   double aX = Math.Pow(it.x - newCircle.x, 2);
                   double aY = Math.Pow(it.y - newCircle.y, 2);
                   double Dif = Math.Abs(aX - aY);
                   double ra1 = it.r / 2;
                   double ra2 = it.r / 2;

                   double raDif = Math.Pow(ra1 + ra2, 2);
                   if ((raDif + 1) > Dif) return false;

                  //if (squaredDist < sumR*sumR) return false;
               }
               return true; // no existing circle overlaps



        }

        public int[] GenerateNewCircle(int maxSize)
        {
            int x, y;
                Random randomMember = new Random();

                x =  randomMember.Next(0,maxSize);
            if (x - 50 < 0)
                y = randomMember.Next(x + 50, maxSize);
            else if (x + 50 > 600)
                y = randomMember.Next(0, x - 50);
            else
                // in this case, x splits the range 0..n into 2 subranges.
                // get a random number and skip the "gap" if necessary
                y = randomMember.Next(0, maxSize - 50);
            if (y > x - 50)
            {
                y += 20;
            }

            int[] abc = new int[2];
            abc[0] = x;
            abc[1] = y;


            return abc;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Size sizeShape = new Size("SomeWidth" , "SomeHeight");
        List<Retangle> rects = new List<Retangle>(); 

        Random r = new Random();

    while(rects.count != "someCount")
    {
        Point rPoint = new Point(r.Next(500) , r.Next(500))
        bool isNew = true;
        foreach(Rectangle r in rects)
        {
            if(r.contains(rPoint))
                isNew = false;
        }
        if(isNew)
           rects.Add(GetRect(rPoint  , sizeShape)); 
    }

        private Rectangle GetRect(Point p , Size s)
        {
            return new Rectangle(p,s);
        }
```

> After than you can use from rects ,
>   rects has random coordinates.

Comment: Hmmm, you're referencing some variables that you're not instantiating here. You're also taking a brute-force approach instead of solving the actual problem. Also, you're checking to see if a List<Rectangle> contains a point object...

Comment: hi, is almost that, but how can i see if an rectangle is not overlaping another?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link to let you know how to create [Random Numbers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

You have to keep in mind that you will generate random numbers, but you also have to make sure the numbers generated will not make objects overlap.

Comment: but if i used a random, the coordenates may be wrong, because the subnode, is for example in x:500;y:500, and then the subnode gives for example in x:40;y60 . that is because random isn't ok :S

Comment: Bottom line: you need random numbers, but you also need to treat and validate them after you get them. If they do not suit you, you should get new numbers. Caveat: beware of endless loops. If you keep dismissing numbers generated, then your numbers are not *as random* as you first thought them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this being pretty poorly worded, I believe what you are looking for is the Random class. It is instantiated as such:

```
Random thisRandom = new Random();
```

Then from there, if you want to generate a random coordinate, you need to know the maximum possible X and Y coordinates. Knowing these will allow you to generate X and Y coordinates within the given canvas as such:

```
int maxX = 500; //This is the maximum X value on your canvas
int maxY = 500; //This is the maximum Y value on your canvas

int newX, newY;

newX = thisRandom.Next(maxX);
newY = thisRandom.Next(maxY);
```

While its not the absolute best in terms of "true" randomization this should give you what you need.

Comment: but if i used a random, the coordenates may be wrong, because the subnode, is for example in x:500;y:500, and then the subnode gives for example in x:40;y60 . that is because random isn't ok :S

Comment: Then determine a suitable distance from the Node. If the suitable distance is 20, then do newX = thisRandom.Next(2*20) - 20; And then subtract this from your initial x value. This will ensure that your new x value is within 20 pixels of your previous one.

Comment: but how can i check it if in a radius of 20?

Comment: @Luis I just answered this. If you have a radius of 20, then you would do newX = thisRandom.Next(2*20) - 20; This will give you an integer in the range (-20, 20]. You can then add this to your initial x coordinate and voila you will have an X value within the radius you want.